# sqlSave, How to Write data to SQL developer having date Column containing hyphen

Tags: r, rodbc

I have a dataframe `data`,Which Contains the columns having integers,and columns containing date and time,As shown

```
>head(data,2)

      PRESSURE     AMBIENT_TEMP  OUTLET_PRESSURE COMP_STATUS   DATE      TIME        predict
1        14           65            21            0        2014-01-09   12:45:00     0.6025863
2        17           65            22            0        2014-01-10   06:00:00     0.6657910
```

And Now i'm going to write this back to Sql database by the chunck

```
 sqlSave(channel,data,tablename = "ANL_ASSET_CO",append = T)
```

Where channel is connection name,But this gives error

```
 [RODBC] Failed exec in Update
 22018 1722 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: invalid number
```

But When i try excluding the date column ,it writes back without any error.

```
 > sqlSave(channel,data[,c(1:4,7)],tablename = "ANL_ASSET_CO",append = T)
 > sqlSave(channel,data[,c(1:4,6:7)],tablename = "ANL_ASSET_CO",append = T)
```

Because of the date column the data is not writing to ORACLE SQL developer,Could be problem with the hyphen.
How can i write , Any help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>class(data$DATE)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

So had to change the data type as character

```
>data$DATE <- as.character(data$DATE)
>sqlSave(channel,data,tablename = "ANL_ASSET_CO",append=T)
```

This one worked!!